# Editing Magento Checkout Form

Tags: magento, checkout

On clicking "place order" in Magento, I want to capture some of its values and feed them to the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.jambopay.com/JPExpress.aspx" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="jp_item_type" value="cart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_item_name" value="test shop"/>
<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="455879"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_business" value="business@yourdomain.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_amount_1" value="51"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_amount_2" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_amount_5" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_payee" value="email@yourcustomer.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_shipping" value="company name"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_rurl" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/testpost/Result.aspx?ii=0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_furl" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/testpost/Result.aspx?ii=1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_curl" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/testpost/Result.aspx?ii=2"/>
<input type="image" src="https://www.jambopay.com/jambohelp/jambo/rsc/paymentsbyJamboPay.jpg"/>
</form>
```

The values include:
Order Number,
Total Amount,
Customers Email Address,

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of order after save order is called you can get last order id from this methods
`$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();` 
once you have order id then load order like this 
`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);`
 and you can get all details of order